# Knockout: Best Way To Create Links In Rendered Content Bound To ViewModel Functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout to bind an element:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: someCollection">
    <p data-bind="html: someTextProperty"></p>
</div>
```

However, there's text in someTextProperty that I want to turn into hyperlinks that interact with the ViewModel and one of its functions.

Is there an easy, supported way to perform bindings on dynamically rendered content after it's rendered? Is an afterRender binding in foreach (which requires a lot of logic to make sure I'm targeting the right element) the only thing available?

EDIT:

In my real-world scenario, someTextProperty would look something like this:

```
This is a paragraph with some <tag data-val="foo">tagged</tag> text.
```

...and I'm currently converting it to something like this:

```
This is a paragraph with some <a onclick="viewModel.DoSomething(\'foo\')">tagged</a> text.
```

...but referencing the view model function directly in the link feels a bit dirty, so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: You might want components. Or maybe the `html` binding. It's hard to tell what makes sense for your situation. 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a clean fit. someTextProperty is basically a long paragraph with occasional, random, optional hyperlinks, and I want those links to call a method of the view model. Components and the html binding don't seem to help with that.

Comment: Can you make a simplified example of what you might get as text and how you might like to have it transformed?

Comment: Done. Oh, and I did need to use the html binding (thanks for the heads up in the last comment!), but that wasn't really the detail I meant to ask about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what it takes is a custom binding handler that wraps the html binding and applies bindings to the new code. I've just made a magical computed to transform the original data into the desired html, and bound the computed.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.boundHtml = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.html.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(element.children, function(node) {
      console.debug("Bind", node);
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(node, context);
    });
  }
};

data = 'This is a paragraph with some <tag data-val="foo">tagged</tag> text.';

function myTransform() {
  return 'This is a paragraph with some <a data-bind="click: DoSomething.bind(null, \'foo\')">tagged</a> text.';
}

vm = {
  someTextProperty: ko.observable(data),
  transformed: ko.computed({
    deferEvaluation: true,
    read: myTransform
  }),
  DoSomething: function(arg) {
    console.debug("Doing something with", arg);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="boundHtml: transformed"></div>
```

Comment: I haven't integrated it yet, but that looks like just what I needed. Thanks!